# Bug finding neighboring cells in "Game of life" using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a version of "Conway's game of life" in python and pygame, but I am having trouble with finding neighboring cells. Below is most of the code. I edited out unnecessary parts, because the problem is with the cell.get_neighbors() function. If you want to see the rest of it, you can read it [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1H5mXC96zeEurJcQUgGP-gAlFxOFgR5boK-INO0XqOGA/edit?usp=sharing).

```
def main():
    while True:

        draw_board()
        update_cells()

        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(FPS)

def update_cells():
    event_handling()

    if clicked == True:
        cell = where_clicked(mousex, mousey)
        if cell != None:
            print (cell.get_neighbors())

class cell:
    #The problem is with this function
    def get_neighbors(self):
        neighbors = []
        for y in (-1, 0, 1):
            for x in (-1, 0, 1):
                neighbor = find_cell(x + self.x, y + self.y)
                if neighbor not in (None, self):
                    neighbors.append(neighbor)
                    #I added neighbor.switch() so that I could easily see which cells were being returned by the get_neighbors() function.
                    neighbor.switch()
        return neighbors

    def switch(self):
        if self.alive == False:
            self.alive = True
        else:
            self.alive = False

def find_cell(x, y):
    for CELL in board:
        if CELL.x == x:
            if CELL.y == y:
                return CELL

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The get_neighbors() function as it's written above should turn all 8 adjacent cells black, but instead it turns 4-10 seemingly random cells black. I made [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_genGXpST77RFZ6RUtrZmZaM28/edit?usp=sharing) screen recording to demonstrate the problem. As you can see, if I click in the top-left, or at the top, it works just like it should, but when I click in the middle, it does something like this:

http://www.imagesup.net/?di=8140372670715

or this:

http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1514037265628

or this:

http://www.imagesup.net/?di=1014037266308

Am I missing something? Because cell.get_neighbors() should be working correctly. find_cell() works correctly, and

```
for y in (-1, 0, 1):
    for x in (-1, 0, 1):
        ...
        find_cell(x, y)
```

should find every adjacent cell like this.

```
(-1, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1)
( 0, -1), ( 0, 0), ( 0, 1)
( 1, -1), ( 1, 0), ( 1, 1)
```

and

```
if neighbor not in (None, self):
```

should prevent it from returning any cell outside of the board, and from returning itself. (Since a cell can't be it's own neighbor).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your posted code you have

```
neighbor = find_cell(x + self.x, y + self.y)
```

However, in your linked code you have

```
for y in (-1, 0, 1):
    for x in (-1, 0, 1):
        x += self.x
        y += self.y
```

Note how in your images, the switched cells seem to step downwards. This is because you are modifying `y` *three times* in the inner loop, before it is reset to one of the [-1, 0, 1] values. Running just the loop, and printing out the values, you'll see `y` change in the inner loop when it shouldn't.

It looks fine when clicking at the top because the incremented y value `self.y` is zero. Note also how the stepping gets more exaggerated the further down the window you click.

Change your running code to the code you posted, and it should work fine.

Comment: Of course! I knew it was something stupidly simple. I edited it just like you said and it works perfectly. Thanks!